# Category Theory Zoo

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, online-resources

There are a few very useful websites when it comes to either finding a specific object with certain properties (and maybe lacking other properties) or finding out which properties a certain object has.
For example, there are [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org) and [Topospaces](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) for topological spaces (the former having an amazingly powerful search language).
I suppose on a more classical level there is also the Atlas of Finite Groups for (as one would hope) finite groups.

**Is there a similar reference (website, article, book, etc.) for categories?**
That is if I want to know if a certain category is complete, or admits a monoidal structure, or if I want an example of a locally-small-but-not-small category, is there somewhere where I can look such things up.
I've done a fair amount of looking for such a thing but have not found one so far.
I know that the nLab often has information, but it often goes far beyond what I need and omits some of the more basic things.

Comment: There isn't. There should be.

Comment: I'm coming up to exam season, so I won't have much time, but I've started a project for this: https://github.com/thosgood/CatZoo . Any help or comments would be more than appreciated, if anybody else wants to get involved.

Comment: The nLab https://ncatlab.org/nlab/ is continuously being built. If everyone goes and adds his favorite basic property of a category there, eventually it will contain them.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but there are also computation frameworks for category theory, like: https://algebraicjulia.github.io/Catlab.jl/stable/
I think those are important because at some point it would be great to have a "search for an object of this kind" possibility. And that could be realised if categories are properly represented in some framework rather than a book/wiki.

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers for topology.pi-base.org. If any category theorist is interested in building categories.pi-base.org please feel free to reach out to discuss!

Comment: https://smallcats.info/ has just launched, which is very much in line with what I was asking for!